# Could not import package. Warning SQL72012: Error to import bacpac file

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, warnings

Could not import package.

> Warning SQL72012: The object [-Production_Data] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
>
> Warning SQL72012: The object [Production_Log] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
>
> Error SQL72014: Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider:
>
> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AuthorizationEvents_AuthorizationId_Authorizations_Id". The conflict occurred in database "Production", table "dbo.Authorizations", column 'Id'.
>
> Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script: PRINT N'Checking constraint: FK_AuthorizationEvents_AuthorizationId_Authorizations_Id [dbo].[AuthorizationEvents]'; ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AuthorizationEvents] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_AuthorizationEvents_AuthorizationId_Authorizations_Id];

I was trying to import a `.bacpac` file from Azure into SQL Server with apply data tier option, everything was great until the problem appeared.

I need some help please

Comment: Could you please provide your approach?

Answer (score 0):

I assume considering this scenario where in order to restore a contained database coming from Azure SQL Database into an on-premise SQL Server instance the "contained database authentication" property must be enabled.

Could you please to execute below command and see if this helps in your case:

```
sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Comment: Didn't work, says Operation Failed importing database, updating database and importing package schema.

Comment: Ok. as the error message states "conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint" please try to disable the foreign key constraint before importing the data and then re-enable it after the import is complete.